# how to align 2 span left and right without using float

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and trying to put a button inside a fake read only text box, this is roughly what i have achieved [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/boobLfkf/8/)

this div is in a table with `.table-responsive` thus, if i use float, it overflows when the btn is very [wide](http://jsfiddle.net/boobLfkf/9/)

What should i do considering the "testing" text is of variable length but my button is fixed

```
<div class="my-container">
    <span>testing</span>
    <span class="btn btn-success pull-right">btn</span>
</div>
```

Comment: If the text is too wide and forces the button to overflow when floated, it is because without overflowing the text and button would be on top of each other, which is just as bad. If you limit the overall width, then you have to limit the width of the text. You can set it to replace text overflow with ellipsis, or make the overall width wider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your button width is fixed, then you can try something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/1dm7c8jh/

**html:**

```
<div class="my-container">
    <span>testing</span>
    <span class="btn btn-success pull-right">btn</span>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.my-container {
    background-color: #fffaae;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right: 120px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
}

.btn {
    background-color: #9AD2FF;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use truncating class from bootstrap, to truncate your text in both of the spans, or any one span.

its mentioned here, or simply use the css for the same;

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#less-mixins-truncating

```
    // Mixin
.text-overflow() {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

// Usage
.branch-name {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 200px;
  .text-overflow();
}
```